# Angular 2 Cannot read property '0' of undefined error

Tags: angular

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }            from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/common';
import { Md5 } from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';

import { User }        from '../user/user';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/dashboard/dashboard.component.css'],
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  loginCheck: boolean = false;

  constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {   }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.loginCheck = false;
  }

  doLogin(event: any, username: string, password: string) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let data = {
      UserName: username,
      Password: Md5.hashStr(password)
    }
    return this.userService.login('http://url/api/Authorization/Login', data);
  }



  userDetail(user: User){
    let link = ['/userdetail', user.id];
    this.router.navigate(link);
  }

}
```

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { User } from './user';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    testUrl: string = '../config/users';
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getUser(){
      return this.http.get(this.testUrl)
                      .toPromise()
                      .then(response => response.json().data as User[])
                      .catch(this.handleError); 
    }

    getUserDetail(id: number){
      return this.getUser().then(users => users.find(user => user.id === id));
    }

    login(url: string, data: Object){
      let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
      return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data));

    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
      console.error('An error occurred', error);
      return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="!loginCheck" class="login center-block">
  <h5>Giriş Yap</h5>
  <form role="form" (submit)="doLogin($event, username.value, password.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" #username class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adı">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" #password class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Şifre">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Giriş Yap</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Error console output:

[image: Error console output]

Angular entry I wrote to test service will make mistakes in getting service and component 2 senselessly. I put the code for the service and codes of components did not write html codes passwor there was already successfully withdrawn username'm sending request. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Not sure what, exactly, you're trying to say at the end. Maybe edit your question to clarify? Very hard to understand.

Comment: Please put your HTML here too, as I see `dashboard.component.html` could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, where or how you call the `doLogin()` method, but since you're calling on an `event` object, I guess it's the `(click)` handler for your login button.

Going from there, I think the return won't do anything useful for you and you should insetad subscribe to the `Observable` you get from the service, otherwise it won't get called:

```ts
  doLogin(event: any, username: string, password: string) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let data = {
      UserName: username,
      Password: Md5.hashStr(password)
    }

    this.userService.login('http://url/api/Authorization/Login', data)
        subscribe((data) => {
            // do something with the api response
        });
  }
```

Comment: unfortunately not the solution

Comment: Okay, but definitely part of it, though. Since without a `subscribe` the `http.post` never gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Check the import file in memory backend component in the `app.module.ts` by preventing the willingness to fix them, wipe the outside with URLs.